# Use .contains() to retrieve values from DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new with NoSQL Databases and am stuck with a problem. I just want to get keys from a table in DynamoDB that contains a specific value. I know that for key equals I can use:

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('year').eq(1992) 
)
```

But I can't use:

```
 response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('year').contain('1992') 
)
```

The error is:

> Key object has no attribute contain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DynamoDB doesn't follow to use `contain` for key attribute on Query API. You can use only **equals** for partition key attribute.

**CONTAINS** can be used with **LIST or SET** data type only. Also, it can be used only on `FilterExpression`.

> CONTAINS : Checks for a subsequence, or value in a set.
>
> CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a"
>   can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.

Answer (score 5):

People looking at this question in 2023 (At least with the current version of Boto!) are going to be misled to the other answers here.

You can now check if a value contains a substring by using the Attr object, not Key.

```
  response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('key').contains(string)
  )
```

Comment: This is probably fine but it should be called out that scans are almost never best practice. Use query instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check **all the methods for Key class:**

https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/dynamodb/conditions.py

Key class is inherited from **class AttributeBase** and here are nothing like contains, only greater than or starts with etc.